# How to send multiline text via jquery ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, text, csv

I have a textarea in a html form where I put:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Then I press button and send the text via jquery ajax to a php script that handles the ajax request and needs to enter each line to db table as a separate row.

Currently, I send the string as

```
encodeURIComponent($('#multiline_text').val()) in data: variable in jquery
```

then I'm trying to break the text into array  using `explode('\n', $multiline_text)` in the php file and then enter each row to db table using foreach.

But I'm getting only one array element and that element is being entered as one row only into the db table and the row has value: "line1 line2 line3" without quotes, instead of having 3 separate rows in the table with values:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

What should I do?

Comment: Text have to be prefixed with four spaces for a block of code. But, you **also have to prefix the block with an empty line**. If you want to mark inline code, enclose the phrase with backticks (`).

Comment: An answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183466/new-line-problem-when-doing-ajax-post-with-jquery helped me to sovle this. Maybe someone has more elegant solution?

Comment: Try an ajax post instead.  Maybe something with the encode is messing with it.

Comment: @iLLin: I'm already using it: $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',

Comment: Is this: `explode('\n', $multiline_text)` the exact code? If so, try using double quotes:`explode("\n", $multiline_text)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried;

```
explode("\n", $multiline_text);
```

it will need double quotes to recognize the new line.

Comment: Yes, the OP mentions that in the question.

Comment: Here's the answer and it works. Does anybody knows why is that? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#101484

Comment: Here's another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997336/explode-php-string-by-new-line

Comment: When you use double quotes it only splits the string at the first occurrence.  If you use single quotes it splits at them all.

Comment: @Archer: Isn't it contrary? It doesnt' work with single quotes, while it works using double quotes

Comment: more information can be found here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double